# jQuery Isotope - how to reset items to original order

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I've set up a page of staff bios using the awesome jQuery Isotope plugin.

The layout is a standard 4 column grid and all the items are the same size. When a user clicks on an item, the previous items in it's row are appended to the layout using the "insert" method and then the clicked item increases size 4x, to full width. This works perfectly, however when the large bio is closed (on click), I would like to reset the layout to its orignal order (the order on page load).

I have tried using the "sortBy" option set to "original-order" but it doesn't seem to reset the order to the original.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `original-order` works fine check here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/qxT6F/, check here, you may have some other problem in your code. Share some code with us so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you yoused Isotope's shuffle and/or reLayout method? Then, delete those. Have you looked also [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/adding-items.html)? You probably did. A link to a sandbox or fiddle always helps...